# Context switching - ucontext_t and makecontext()

Tags: c, context-switch, ucontext

I am studying context switching in C programming and have found the following example code on the Internet. I am trying to figure out whether only `makecontext()` function can trigger a function that does something. The other functions such as `setcontext()`, `getcontext()`, and `swapcontext()` are used for setting the context.

The `makecontext()` attaches a function and its parameter(s) to a context, does the function stick to the context all the time until a change is committed to it?

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <ucontext.h>
  4 #define MEM 64000
  5 
  6 ucontext_t T1, T2, Main;
  7 ucontext_t a;
  8 
  9 int fn1()
 10 {
 11   printf("this is from 1\n");
 12   setcontext(&Main);
 13 }
 14 
 15 void fn2()
 16 {
 17   printf("this is from 2\n");
 18   setcontext(&a);
 19   printf("finished 1\n");
 20 }
 21 
 22 void start()
 23 {
 24   getcontext(&a);
 25   a.uc_link=0;
 26   a.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(MEM);
 27   a.uc_stack.ss_size=MEM;
 28   a.uc_stack.ss_flags=0;
 29   makecontext(&a, (void*)&fn1, 0);
 30 }
 31 
 32 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 33 {
 34   start();
 35   getcontext(&Main);
 36   getcontext(&T1);
 37   T1.uc_link=0;
 38   T1.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(MEM);
 39   T1.uc_stack.ss_size=MEM;
 40   makecontext(&T1, (void*)&fn1, 0);
 41   swapcontext(&Main, &T1);
 42   getcontext(&T2);
 43   T2.uc_link=0;
 44   T2.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(MEM);
 45   T2.uc_stack.ss_size=MEM;
 46   T2.uc_stack.ss_flags=0;
 47   makecontext(&T2, (void*)&fn2, 0);
 48   swapcontext(&Main, &T2);
 49   printf("completed\n");
 50   exit(0);
 51 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`makecontext` writes the function info into a context, and it will remain there until it is overwritten by something else.  `getcontext` overwites the entire context, so would overwrite any function written there by a previous call to `makecontext`.  Likewise, `swapcontext` completely overwrites the context pointed at by its first argument.

The basic idea is that a `u_context` contains a snapshot of part of the process context at some time.  It contains all the machine registers, stack info, and signal masks.  It does NOT include any memory map or file descriptor state.  The state in the `u_context` is precisely all the state you need to manipulate in order to implement threads or coroutines.

**edit**

`swapcontext(&current, &another)` saves the current context in `current` and switches to `another`.  At some later point, the code (runnning from `another` context) may switch back to `current` (with another call to `swapcontext`) or it might switch to some third context.
When a context ends (the function set into it with `makecontext` returns), if some context is pointed at by its `uc_link` field, it will switch to that context.  But if `uc_link` is NULL, then the thread (and process if there's only one thread) will exit -- other contexts that are not running will just be abandoned.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. I thought the swapcontext(&currentContext, &anotherContext) would sitch to &anotherContext first, after that finishes, it will continue finish the &currentContext. Is this understanding not correct? I appreciate your reply